# Do this required many to many relationship?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

This is my db design:

```
Portfolio:
   -  id
   -  name
   -  invested
   -  total
   - ...... etc
```

And my second table

```
Investments: 
   -  id
   - portfolio_id
   - amount
   --- etc
```

so according to the logic, a each user can have only one portfolio and each portfolio can have multiple investments:

So basically "portfolio" can have multiple investments and "investments" can also have multiple Portfolio right ? (each user have one Portfolio), thus should i use many to many or one to many ?

As each user have unique profile, investments relates to their profile alone ( it cant be accessed by others ) so should i use one to many here ?

Comment: "...and "investments" can also have multiple Portfolio right ?..." -- not according to this design. An investment can only be tied to a single portfolio since you specified a single fk.

Comment: Yes ! One portfolio can have multiple investments and but that same investment cant be related to other users right ? Ex: if A has a investment as X then B cant relate to X ( as it can have a unique investment ) so i thought one to many suits this !

Comment: You are right. As it is written, the relationship is one to many.

Comment: So when it will be many to many  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a Associative Entity to bridge between the two tables instead of relying on a many-to-many relationship.

[image: Bridge Table to facilitate Many-To-Many]

This is useful if you you need to have an investment mapped to multiple portfolios, but to answer your question, if you did it this way, each investment could be linked to more than one portfolio, which does not make any sense. While it is possible for the same stock name to be invested, this would require a separate table for the investment_options, not the same exact investment linked to a different portfolio. Your table should not ever be many-to-many.

Since you said that each user has a unique profile, the correct answer for your problem would be to use a One-To-Many relationship, linking one `Portfolio` to many `Investments`.

[image: One-To-Many Table]

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment that doesn't fit in the comments section.

For the relationship to be many-to-many you'll need to add an extra table that represents the relationship. For example:

```
Portfolio:
   - id
   - name
   - invested
   - total

Portfolio_Investment:
   - portfolio_id
   - investment_id

Investments: 
   - id
   - amount
```

Notice the column `portfolio_id` is not longer present in `Investments`.

Comment: Ya, I know how many to many works ! But am asking is my requirements need that or shall i continue with just one to many ?

Comment: @christine11 - _"portfolio" can have multiple investments and "investments" can also have multiple Portfolio_ implies _many-to-many_.  Period.  Full stop.  TheImplaer's schema is excellent.

Comment: I know that, but i think you guys havent understood my question !